# geom_ribbon() using multiple datasets in ggplot2: Error in as.POSIXct

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, posixlt

I am using multiple datasets in ggplot2 to create a time series of event occurrences. The plan is to plot the mean lines (mean being average date of occurrence) of two datasets over time, and use `geom_ribbon()` to depict the range between +1 and -1 standard deviation above and below the mean (listed below in columns `sdv_pos` and `sdv_neg` representing +1 and -1 respectively).

I am able to plot the two mean lines. However, when I insert geom_ribbon I get the following error:

> Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied".

I've tried converting the columns used in the `geom_ribbon()` line using `as.POSIXct()` with the origin, but it has not worked. I only get this error with  `geom_ribbon()`, not `geom_line()`.

Here are the two datasets:
Data1:

```
   sdv_pos   stv_neg   year data1_mean 
 1976-03-20 1976-03-14 1997 1976-03-17 
 1976-02-18 1976-01-18 1998 1976-02-03 
 1976-02-12 1976-01-06 1999 1976-01-24 
 1976-03-02 1976-01-07 2000 1976-02-04 
 1976-01-10 1976-01-10 2001 1976-01-10 
 1976-04-21 1976-02-19 2002 1976-03-21 1
```

Data2:

```
   sdv_pos    sdv_neg  year data2_mean
 1976-04-24 1976-03-10 1997 1976-04-02
 1976-04-21 1976-01-27 1998 1976-03-10
 1976-04-21 1976-01-20 1999 1976-03-07
 1976-03-23 1976-01-04 2000 1976-02-12
 1976-05-05 1976-02-08 2001 1976-03-23
 1976-05-01 1976-01-29 2002 1976-03-16
```

Here is the code I'm using for this. Note that when I remove `geom_ribbon()` the plot works. However when I include `geom_ribbon()` I get the error.

```
graph1<- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = Data1, aes(x = year, y = data2_mean), color = "blue") +
  geom_ribbon(data = Data1, aes(x=data2_mean, ymax=sdv_pos, ymin=sdv_neg), fill="pink", alpha=.5)+
  geom_line(data = Data2, aes(x = year, y=data2_mean), color = "red") +
  geom_ribbon(data = Data2, aes(x=data2_mean, ymax=sdv_pos, ymin=sdv_neg), fill="yellow", alpha=.5)
```

Note that the year for the x axis and year for the data values are not the same. I use 1976 just to keep the mean line on the same date/month, otherwise the y-axis will extent to include all the years in the study

Comment: This is still an error I'm encountering using various datasets and different approaches. Please let me know if any additional information is needed to address this question and I'll be happy to follow up

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by changing the command to

```
geom_ribbon(data = Data1, aes(x=data2_mean, ymax=sdv_pos, ymin=sdv_neg), fill="pink", alpha=.5)+
```

The difference being what the x value is. I thought I had to incorporate the  mean as a centerline for the ribbon, but what it does is simply shades in the space between the two lines (sdv_pos, sdv_neg), and needs x for the x-axis to shade the area as it goes.

Seems obvious but I wanted to post an answer here in case anyone runs into the same problem